# Please reconsider "What is the rationale for a separate “National Insurance” tax in the UK? "

Tags: discussion, moderation, off-topic

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/37154/what-is-the-rationale-for-a-separate-national-insurance-tax-in-the-uk) was closed as off-topic. While it was open, someone posted an excellent answer, but it was to a slightly different question to the one I asked.

Once my actual question had been clarified, it turned out to be off-topic. I since re-posted it on the politics site.

Rather than allow that excellent answer to disappear, I rewrote the question to fit the answer, but it still has most of the close votes from when it was off-topic.

Please reconsider that question in its present form.

Answer (score 2):

**FLIP FLOP - MOD WAFFLING ALERT**

I opened it based on financial literacy

Firstly, if the answers devolved into political back and forth, I would remove it.  The answer that is there seems to be thoughtful and balance.

The reason I wouldn't unilaterally open it is exactly because you found a better home at politics.SE.  If you wanted to know why how or what, all of those are answered very well at politics.

It isn't so much that the question is bad or poor, just in the wrong arena.  (And I fully acknowledge it is a fine line.)

Because you already asked a question at politics, we cannot migrate it.  So I think the best thing to do is to edit the question with very clear link to politics (and it is done) and then leave it closed.  (again, already done.)

No need to delete, but no need to re-open.